# WPF lazy binding context menu items source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, caliburn.micro

I successfully bind `MenuModel` to `MenuItem.ItemsSource`. However, the items should be contextualized. Right now, I populate the ViewModel collection and the data is ready to be bound to items source, but that's not covering all my scenarios.

I need to re-populate the ViewModel collection when the context menu is opening, that is, my goal is to only populate the collection at context menu opening, because earlier don't make sense (the items should be contextualized by ListBox SelectedItem).

**XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="ActionMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource ActionMenuItemIcon}" />
    <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding IsCheckable, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Action}" />
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding ActionParameter}" />
</Style>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:MenuModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Header}" Style="{StaticResource ActionMenuItemStyle}"
                      UsesItemContainerTemplate="True" ItemContainerTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ActionMenuItemContainerTemplateSelector}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:SeparatorMenuModel}">
    <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<ContextMenu x:Key="OneItem">
            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static resx:StudioResources.Advanced}">

                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static resx:StudioResources.MoveToRoutineMenu}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.Routines, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                          UsesItemContainerTemplate="True" 
                          ItemContainerTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ActionMenuItemContainerTemplateSelector}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public IObservableCollection<IMenuModel> Routines { get; private set; }
protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);

        GetParent().Routines.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            Routines.Clear();
            var names = GetParent().Routines.Where(r => r != GetParent().ActiveRoutine).Take(5).OrderBy(r => r);
            var menus = names.Select(name => new MenuModel(name, new MenuAction<string>(MoveToRoutine), name)).ToList();
            menus.ForEach(m => m.WithEditor(GetParent()));
            Routines.AddRange(menus);
        };
    }
```

I listen to an event to re-populate the collection, but actually I need to listen to several other events, and I wonder if there is a clean way, like populate on context menu opening.

Comment: Just bind a collection. Are you saying that items in the submenu will change depending on `ListBox.SelectedItem`? In that case, repopulate the collection when `ListBox.SelectedItem` changes. If you absolutely insist on making this as difficult and error prone as possible, handle the `ContextMenuOpening` of the context menu's owner and do everything in code behind.

Comment: the items will change when `ListBox.SelectedItem` change, yes, but there are other events that will influence the menu items, that's why I want to only populate at opening. That way I will only call `Clear` and `AddRange` when needed (this is an heavy operation).

Comment: How many menu items do you have?

Comment: not many, but the application is huge (it's an IDE), so the less useless UI events propagated better

Comment: Well, `ContextMenuOpening` is raised every time the menu is about to open, and at no other time, so that sounds like a good place to do anything that you want to happen then and only then.

Comment: `ContextMenuOpening` works. Going further, what if I need to **only** popuplate submenus when user mouse over its parent? Suppose I have context menu like Item1, Item2, Advanced (inside advanced: MenuToPopulateWhenMouseOver). So I would only populate the 3rd level when user goes to Advanced & MouseOver/Focus/Select the submenu.

Comment: You could bind ContextMenu.ItemsSource to an `IEnumerable` of a class `MyMenuItem`. The class would have a Command property, a HeaderText property, and a ChildItems property of type `IEnumerable<MyMenuItem>`. In a MenuItem style, you'd wire up those properties with bindings to the MenuItem properties. I don't know if the `ItemsSource` bindings would enumerate the ienumerables only when the submenus open; probably not. But you should not worry about that optimization until you encounter performance issues at runtime. You're going too far with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147482/discussion-between-jobadiniz-and-ed-plunkett).